# How to get the Attachement File

Tags: c#

Here I am trying to get all the part of an email separately like body, attachments, address part also So I have the below code . So can I get the attachment files also by using same technique( Using PropertySet class or define RequestedBodyType to something)???

**Is there any way to get the contents of Attachment files of any type and I don't need to change the code too much??**

```
// Get the Unread mails from the server
SearchFilter itemFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false);

// get the emails from Inbox folder
FindItemsResults<Item> emails = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, itemFilter, view);


foreach (EmailMessage em in emails)
{
    itempropertyset.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.HTML;

    em.Load(itempropertyset);
    em.IsRead = true;
    em.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);

    EmailProList.HTMLBody = em.Body.Text;

    itempropertyset.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
    em.Load(itempropertyset);

    EmailProList.Body = em.Body.Text;
    itempropertyset.RequestedBodyType = 

    EmailProList.ToEmailAddr = em.Sender.Address.ToString(); //JG Changed

    EmailProList.Subject = em.Subject.ToString();

    EmailProList.Type = "Feedback";

}
```

Comment: Is there not an `Attachments` property on the `EmailMessage` object?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_members.aspx

Comment: @David this is my third day in .Net so let me check

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attachments like this:

```
EmailMessage email = item as EmailMessage;

foreach(FileAttachment file in email.FileAttachments)
{
   // Process the attachment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the attachments by this way.

```
                if (message.HasAttachments && message.Attachments[0] is FileAttachment)
                {
                    FileAttachment fileAttachment = message.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
                    Console.WriteLine("email" + fileAttachment.Name);
                    fileAttachment.Load(@"D:\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
                }
```